# The input is not working properly

Tags: c

The user has to input a number between 1 and 15 both inclusive. But my code accepts every single number. Even if I enter a negative number it does not call get the user input again. What should I change in the code? Thanks!

```
int enterNum(){

    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 15.\n");
    int input = 0;
    scanf(" %d", &input);

    while(input < 1 && input > 15){
        printf("Invalid input! Please try again!");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Use a loop. You use some weird kind of recursion. Also always check the result of `scanf`!

Comment: a number cant be less than 1 and great than 15 at the same time!, scanf is also not ideal do some research on other user input options Google is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input < 1 && input > 15` will never be true.

Use `input < 1 || input > 15` instead.